# pre-emptive refresh of expired JWT token

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga, amazon-cognito

All of the solutions I've found while searching react to a 401 response from an API call before triggering logic to refresh the expired token. In my case, I'm using **react-cognito** which puts the expiry time in the redux store under `cognito.user.signInUserSession.idToken.payload.exp` (integer representing unix time).

I would like to try and implement a scheme where expiry is pre-empted and I'd like to keep this logic separated from my API call code, if practical.

One option I explored is setting a timeout for `currentTime - expiryTime - someBuffer`, but this may be 50 minutes long or more and I've read that long-running timeouts can often be unreliable, having strange performance especially when the browser tab is not in-focus.

Another option I considered was a saga that runs in a loop, initiated by the `LOGGED_IN` action and ended by the `LOGGED_OUT` action, that checks for an almost expired token and refreshes it. On mobile, my understanding is that code execution is paused while the browser is in the background - as such this approach would have an edge case where if the user foregrounds the browser just after token expiry then there's a window of time equal to the loop interval where API calls will 401. The loop interval can be made smaller but the edge condition could never be eliminated.

Is there some scheme that can reliably fire an event/action just before token expiry or, in the case of mobile browsers, fire immediately upon execution-resume if foregrounding happens after the desired refresh time?

Thanks!

David

Answer (score -1):

There is no need for long lived timeouts, simply check each second or so if the token has expired.

```
while(true){
   yield delay(5000);
   if(yield call(checkExpiring)){
      yield relogin();
   }
}
```

There will be a lot of checks, but they don't have any real performance impact. 
That said, I usually write a fetch middleware which checks if the server replies with 401/402 and than reauthenticate and resubmit with the new token.